# SQL Server 2000 query that omits commas in resulting rows?

Tags: select, format, sql-server-2000

Wondering if there is a way to query a SQL Server database and somehow format columns to omit commas in the data if there is any.

Reason for asking is I have 10000+ records and through out the data the `varchar` have data like 3,25% and other 1%.

I'd prefer not to alter the data in the original table thus asking if a select with other functions would do the trick.

I have thought about selecting all the data into a temp table and stripping the commas but that is a lot of work for every time I do the query.

Any info or if its is possible please reply.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) function:

```
SELECT REPLACE(YourColumn, ',', '')
    FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) :

```
REPLACE(YourField,',','')
```